# Ampliar un programa POO con una función nueva a partir de valores previos

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tengo un código que me ha costado dios y ayuda. El juego simula un juego de señales y produce un csv file.

```
import csv
from bisect import bisect
from random import random


class Partida():
    def __init__(self, jugadores, emparejamientos, senales, s, b, x, m):
        self.emparejamientos = emparejamientos
        self.senales = senales
        self.s = s
        self.b = b
        self.x = x
        self.m = m
        self.jugadores = {nombre: Partida.Jugador(senales)
                          for pareja in emparejamientos[0]
                          for nombre in pareja}
        self.memoria = list()
        self.entropy = float()

    def generar_senales(self):

        def with_b(muestra, observa, s, r):
            if not (muestra == observa == 0):
                result = ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra / r) + (
                (0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (self.x) * observa / r) + ((0.98) * self.b * s) + ((self.m / 8))
            else:
                result = ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra / r) + (
                (0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (self.x) * observa / r) + ((0.98) * 0 * s) + ((self.m / 8))
            return result

        def choice(opciones, probs):
            probAcumuladas = list()
            aux = 0
            for p in probs:
                aux += p
                probAcumuladas.append(aux)
            r = random() * probAcumuladas[-1]
            op = bisect(probAcumuladas, r)
            return opciones[op]

        yield dict(zip(self.jugadores.keys(), self.senales))

        r = 1
        while True:
            eleccs = dict.fromkeys(self.jugadores.keys())
            for nombre, inst in self.jugadores.items():
                probs = [with_b(inst.mem_mostradas[op], inst.men_observadas[op], self.s[indx], r)
                         for indx, op in enumerate(self.senales)]
                eleccs[nombre] = choice(self.senales, probs)
            r += 1
            yield eleccs

    def jugar(self):
        gen_sens = self.generar_senales()
        for n, ronda in enumerate(self.emparejamientos):
            senales = next(gen_sens)
            self.memoria.append(senales)

            for jugador1, jugador2 in ronda:
                self.jugadores[jugador1].men_observadas[senales[jugador2]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador2].men_observadas[senales[jugador1]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador1].mem_mostradas[senales[jugador1]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador2].mem_mostradas[senales[jugador2]] += 1


    class Jugador():
        def __init__(self, senales):
            self.mem_mostradas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}
            self.men_observadas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}

def main():
    jugadores = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    senales = ['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4']
    emparejamientos = [[(1, 2), (3, 4)],
                       [(1, 2), (3, 4)],
                       [(1, 4), (2, 3)],
                       [(1, 3), (2, 4)]]

    patron = 1
    s = [0, 0, 0, 0]

    muestras = [{'b': 0.4, 'x': 0.4, 'm': 0.02} for _ in range(100)]

    simulaciones = 10

    estadisticas = {jugador: {muestra: {senal: [0 for ronda in range(1, len(emparejamientos) + 1)]
                                        for senal in senales}
                              for muestra in range(len(muestras))}
                    for jugador in jugadores}

    for mu in range(len(muestras)):
        for _ in range(simulaciones):
            juego = Partida(jugadores, emparejamientos, senales, s, muestras[mu]['b'], muestras[mu]['x'],
                            muestras[mu]['m'])
            juego.jugar()
            for n, ronda in enumerate(juego.memoria):
                for jugador, senal in ronda.items():
                    estadisticas[jugador][mu][senal][n] += 1

        with open('datos.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';',
                                quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            writer.writerow(['Muestra', 'Jugador', 'Ronda', 'Patron', 'b', 'x', 'm'] + senales)

            for jugador in jugadores:
                for mu in range(len(muestras)):
                    for ronda in range(1, len(emparejamientos) + 1):
                        aux = [estadisticas[jugador][mu][senal][ronda - 1] for senal in senales]
                        writer.writerow([mu + 1, jugador, ronda, patron, muestras[mu]['b'], muestras[mu]['x'],
                                         muestras[mu]['m']] + aux)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

El código genera un csv file que contiene una serie de filas y columnas.

En el código, `aux` es una lista que contiene una serie de valores numéricos. En el csv file, los valores de `aux` se imprimen, ronda por ronda, en las columnas S1, S2, S3, S4.

Comprendido lo anterior, lo que deseo es generar una nueva columna de datos en mi csv file. La columna la llamaremos "Ent" y en ella me gustaría escribir, fila por fila (es decir, ronda por ronda) los valores que arroja un código adicional que he escrito.

El código adicional que he escrito hace una serie de operaciones a partir de un string. De alguna manera, calcula lo "variado" que es el string.

Así, lo que hacemos es lo siguiente. Primero convertimos `aux` en un string llamado `auxstring`:

```
auxstring = " ".join(str(x)*x for x in aux)
```

Y a continuación usamos auxstring para calcular el nuevo valor que deseo generar:

```
import math
from sets import Set
st = auxlist
stList = list(st)
alphabet = list(Set(stList))

# calculate the frequency of each symbol in the string
freqList = []
for symbol in alphabet:
    ctr = 0
    for sym in stList:
        if sym == symbol:
           ctr += 1
    freqList.append(float(ctr) / len(stList))
ent = 0.0
for freq in freqList:
    ent = ent + freq * math.log(freq, 2)
ent = -ent
print ent
print int(math.ceil(ent))
```

En definitiva, me gustaría añadir una columna nueva en mi csv file. En dicha columna, aparecerían fila por fila (es decir, ronda por ronda), los valores de `ent`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacer eso basta con que encapsules tu código en una función y posteriormente la llames al construir cada fila del csv pasandole `aux` como argumento.

Antes de esto, unas observaciones:

- El módulo `sets` esta marcado como "deprecated" desde Python 2.6, como supongo que no usarás versiones anteriores a la 2.6 debes usar [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) en su lugar.
- Por otro lado, como lo que haces es contar las repeticiones de cada elemento, puedes hacerlo de forma mucho más eficiente usando `collections.Counter` o simplemente `list.count` dentro de una lista por compresión si solo te importan las frecuencias relativas y no al número el al que pertenece cada una.

Podria quedar algo así:

```
def calcular_ent(lista):
    auxstring = " ".join(str(x)*x for x in lista)
    return int(math.ceil(-sum(freq*math.log(freq, 2)
                                  for freq in (float(auxstring.count(n))/len(auxstring)
                                      for n in set(auxstring)))))
```

Realmente no se que estas haciendo por lo que solo hago una observación:

Con `auxstring = " ".join(str(x)*x for x in aux)` estas metiendo un espacio entre cada grupo y ese espacio es contado como un elemento más. Es decir, en `ent` tienes también calculada la frecuencia relativa del carácter espacio  y que no tiene nada que ver con los datos reales de `aux`. Si por ejemplo tienes `aux = [1,2,3,3]` `alphabet` será `['1', '2', '3', ' ']`. Creo que debería ser `"".join(str(x)*x for x in aux)` pero repito, no se que es lo que haces... :)

Tu código debería ser algo así:

```
import csv
import math
from bisect import bisect
from random import random


class Partida():
    def __init__(self, jugadores, emparejamientos, senales, s, b, x, m):
        self.emparejamientos = emparejamientos
        self.senales = senales
        self.s = s
        self.b = b
        self.x = x
        self.m = m
        self.jugadores = {nombre: Partida.Jugador(senales)
                          for pareja in emparejamientos[0]
                          for nombre in pareja}
        self.memoria = list()
        self.entropy = float()

    def generar_senales(self):

        def with_b(muestra, observa, s, r):
            if not (muestra == observa == 0):
                result = ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra / r) + (
                (0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (self.x) * observa / r) + ((0.98) * self.b * s) + ((self.m / 8))
            else:
                result = ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra / r) + (
                (0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (self.x) * observa / r) + ((0.98) * 0 * s) + ((self.m / 8))
            return result

        def choice(opciones, probs):
            probAcumuladas = list()
            aux = 0
            for p in probs:
                aux += p
                probAcumuladas.append(aux)
            r = random() * probAcumuladas[-1]
            op = bisect(probAcumuladas, r)
            return opciones[op]

        yield dict(zip(self.jugadores.keys(), self.senales))

        r = 1
        while True:
            eleccs = dict.fromkeys(self.jugadores.keys())
            for nombre, inst in self.jugadores.items():
                probs = [with_b(inst.mem_mostradas[op], inst.men_observadas[op], self.s[indx], r)
                         for indx, op in enumerate(self.senales)]
                eleccs[nombre] = choice(self.senales, probs)
            r += 1
            yield eleccs

    def jugar(self):
        gen_sens = self.generar_senales()
        for n, ronda in enumerate(self.emparejamientos):
            senales = next(gen_sens)
            self.memoria.append(senales)

            for jugador1, jugador2 in ronda:
                self.jugadores[jugador1].men_observadas[senales[jugador2]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador2].men_observadas[senales[jugador1]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador1].mem_mostradas[senales[jugador1]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador2].mem_mostradas[senales[jugador2]] += 1


    class Jugador():
        def __init__(self, senales):
            self.mem_mostradas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}
            self.men_observadas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}


def calcular_ent(lista):
    auxstring = " ".join(str(x)*x for x in lista)
    return int(math.ceil(-sum(freq*math.log(freq, 2)
                                  for freq in (float(auxstring.count(n))/len(auxstring)
                                      for n in set(auxstring)))))

def main():
    jugadores = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    senales = ['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4']
    emparejamientos = [[(1, 2), (3, 4)],
                       [(1, 2), (3, 4)],
                       [(1, 4), (2, 3)],
                       [(1, 3), (2, 4)]]

    patron = 1
    s = [0, 0, 0, 0]

    muestras = [{'b': 0.4, 'x': 0.4, 'm': 0.02} for _ in range(100)]

    simulaciones = 10

    estadisticas = {jugador: {muestra: {senal: [0 for ronda in range(1, len(emparejamientos) + 1)]
                                        for senal in senales}
                              for muestra in range(len(muestras))}
                    for jugador in jugadores}

    for mu in range(len(muestras)):
        for _ in range(simulaciones):
            juego = Partida(jugadores, emparejamientos, senales, s, muestras[mu]['b'], muestras[mu]['x'],
                            muestras[mu]['m'])
            juego.jugar()
            for n, ronda in enumerate(juego.memoria):
                for jugador, senal in ronda.items():
                    estadisticas[jugador][mu][senal][n] += 1

        with open('datos.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';',
                                quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            writer.writerow(['Muestra', 'Jugador', 'Ronda', 'Patron', 'b', 'x', 'm'] + senales + ['ent'])

            for jugador in jugadores:
                for mu in range(len(muestras)):
                    for ronda in range(1, len(emparejamientos) + 1):
                        aux = [estadisticas[jugador][mu][senal][ronda - 1] for senal in senales]
                        writer.writerow([mu + 1, jugador, ronda, patron, muestras[mu]['b'], muestras[mu]['x'],
                                         muestras[mu]['m']] + aux + [calcular_ent(aux)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

La salida del csv quedaría algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias @FJSevilla. Algunas observaciones. 1. En efecto, tienes razón, la entropía (ent) que deseo calcular es la de la cadena sin los espacios entre cada caracter. 2. El valor que deseo imprimir en el csv file es ent (que es un número decimal), en lugar de int(math.ceil(ent)) -aunque podríamos hacer dos columnas-. 3. Por otra parte, lo verdaderamente interesante sería calcular ent pero para cada muestra y simulación (es decir, para cada partida con 4 señales iniciales). Y no para la auxstring de un jugador, sino para una auxstring que venga de un sumatorio de señales de todos los jugadores.

Comment: El punto 3, quizá merezca abrir otra pregunta. En ronda 1, en la primera muestra, simulación, cada jugador produce su señal: Jugador 1->[1,0,0,0], Jugador 2->[0,1,0,0], Jug 3->[0,0,1,0], Jug 4-> [0,0,0,1]. Por lo tanto, el sumatorio sería igual a [1,1,1,1]. Esa distribución de señales la transformaríamos en auxstring = '1234'. Y sobre esa cadena calculamos ent. En la segunda ronda, por ejemplo tendríamos, Jug 1 ->[1,0,0,0], Jug 2 ->[1,0,0,0], Jug 3 ->[0,0,1,0], Jug 4->[0,0,1,0]. Sumatorio=[2,0,2,0] y auxstring ='1133'.Con todos los ent de cada simulación haríamos un promedio para cada ronda

Comment: como decía, la respuesta tuya es muy completa, y quizá este último punto deba explicarlo más detenidamente para trabajarlo en otra pregunta. Invocaré tu nombre por si estás por aquí para echar una mano! Gracias de nuevo

Comment: @pyring dado que las explicaciones y aclaraciones suelen ser largas he creado una [sala de chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59466/discussion-between-fjsevilla-and-pyring) por si te interesa hablar por ahí. Saludos.

Comment: Hola @FJSevilla! Viste mis comentarios en el chat? Crees que alguna idea va bien encaminada?

Comment: he estado estos días pensando de nuevo en cómo implementar lo que planteaba en el chat. El problema es que la sala de chat ha quedado bloqueada por inactividad. ¿Podríamos charlar en otra nueva sala? Saludos!